# Proof of partition for a piecewise function

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Let $$f(x) = 0 \,if \, x \leq \frac 12$$
$$f(x) = 1 \,if \, x> \frac12$$

Find a partition P of [0,1] so that $\overline \sum (P,f) - \underline \sum (P,f) < .001$.

I think an answer to this question would be [0.75,  0.80] since it's a flat function so the left and right riemann sums should be identical. Is that right, or am I missing something?

As for the proof, I imagine it'd look something like this:

Consider the partition P = [3/4, 4/5]. By the definition of the function f, f(x) = 1 across the entire interval P. It clearly follows that the left and right Riemann sums would be equal. Therefore, $\overline \sum (P,f) - \underline \sum (P,f) = 0 < .001$.

Comment: What's your definition of a partition? It should be breaking up the interval into several parts, as opposed to just choosing a small portion of it.

Comment: @CalvinLin, I was told a partition was a finite subset of values in increasing order. I just happened to only choose 2 values for this subset, since I thought it worked here.

Comment: In this context a partition is a finite collection of strictly increasing points $x_0 = 0 <  x_1 < ... < x_{n-1} < x_n = 1$. The partition is sometimes described by the intervals $\{ [0,x_1],[x_1,x_2],...,[x_{n-1},1] \}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\overline \sum (P,f) = \sum_{I \in P} \sup f(I) l(I)$, $\underline \sum (P,f) = \sum_{I \in P} \inf f(I) l(I)$. $l(I)$ is the length of the interval $I$.

Choose $\epsilon>0$, and let the partition $P_\epsilon$ be the partition $\{ [0,\frac{1}{2}], [\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}+\epsilon], [\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon, 1] \}$.

Then $\overline \sum (P_\epsilon,f) = 0\frac{1}{2}+ 1\cdot\epsilon + 1 (\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon)$,
$\underline \sum (P,f) = 0\frac{1}{2} + 0 \cdot \epsilon + 1(\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon)$, hence 
$\overline \sum (P,f) - \underline \sum (P,f) = \epsilon$.

If $\epsilon < 0.001$, then $P_\epsilon$ satisfies $\overline \sum (P_\epsilon,f) - \underline \sum (P_\epsilon,f) < 0.001$.

Comment: I have just about no idea what the first line says. Is it necessary? I think I understand your answer without it.

Comment: How do you define $\overline \sum (P,f), \underline \sum (P,f)$?

Comment: @Macavity: Much appreciated!

Comment: @Macavity: My grape riddled brain only sees one $\epsilon$? Feel free to edit as appropriate...

Comment: Your brain seems to be working just fine.  My mistake this time, there's only one $\epsilon$.